# How do you match ^[\s]* in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, space

I'm trying to write a bash script that reads in a file skips commented lines.

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
### read file
IFS=$'\r\n'
while read line; do
    match_pattern="^[:space:]*#"
    if [[ "$line" =~ $match_pattern ]];
        then 
        echo "#####"
        continue
    fi  
    #semicolons and commas are removed everywhere...
    array+=($line)
done <list.txt
```

And this skips lines that begin with a "#", but not lines that begin with spaces and then a pound. ie: `"^\s+#"`

I get the same results using `[:blank:]`.

How should this regular expression be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
while read line; do
    match_pattern="^\s*#"
    if [[ "$line" =~ $match_pattern ]]; then
        echo "#####"
    fi
done
```

**Input**

```
One
#Two
    #Three
# Four
    # Five
####Six
```

**Output**

```
One
#Two
#####
    #Three
#####
# Four
#####
   # Five
#####
####Six
#####
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets in your pattern:

```
match_pattern="^[[:space:]]*#"
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Doesn't start with a hash
- Doesn't start with infinite space followed by a hash

`(?!^#|^\s+#)^.*$`

Yields this result from the code in your question:

```
IFS=$'\r\n'
while read line; do
    match_pattern="^[:space:]*#"
    if [[ "$line" =~ $match_pattern ]];
        then 
        echo "#####"
        continue
    fi  
    array+=($line)
done <list.txt
```

It will match lines which look like this though:

`while read line; do #while loop`

Comment: I think ^\s*# will run a tiny bit faster because it does not have to wait to get to the end of the line before it continues... But that would be good if I were keeping the line rather than skipping the line!

Comment: Oh right. I thought you wanted to match the lines that didn't start with a hash.

Answer (score 0):

`[:space:]` is a bracket expression that will match any of the characters <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>.

`[[:space:]]` is a bracket expression containing a character class: it will match a whitespace character.

```
$ s="   # x"
$ [[ $s =~ ^[:blank:]*# ]] && echo match || echo no match
no match
$ [[ $s =~ ^[[:blank:]]*# ]] && echo match || echo no match
match
```

bash's [extended patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) can handle this as well

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ [[ $s == *([[:blank:]])#* ]] && echo match || echo no match
match
```